# Drilling into outdoor stucco to hang bike

Tags: drill, hanging, stucco

I'm interesting in hanging a [bike hook](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Blue-Hawk-1-Bike-Gray-Steel-Horizontal-Bike-Hook/50218527?cm_mmc=SCE_PLA-_-Kitchens-_-GarageOrganization-_-50218527:Blue_Hawk&CAWELAID=&kpid=50218527&CAGPSPN=pla&store_code=1850&k_clickID=9d0c47c6-adb9-452a-a16a-e7cce45c0923&gclid=CjwKEAjw1PPJBRDq9dGHivbXmhcSJAATZd_B77abrD7DjR0IGlODYBI6oFpPVQVkGtgdyEzazII2XRoCPxbw_wcB) up on my patio outdoors. My outdoor walls appear to be some kind of hard stucco, and I've run a magnetic stud finder over the whole wall and it's all magnetic, indicating to me that there's some kind of metal mesh underneath. Ideally I'd like to hang the hook high enough off the ground on the wall such that the bike doesn't rest on the ground, but if it's significantly easier to hang it such that I don't put that much weight on the hook I can do that.

**What is the best way to drill into the wall and hang the hook?** I have diamond tipped drill bits. I'm just not sure if there's some kind of plywood underneath or if I will hit the metal when drilling. Will I need some kind of expanding screw holder or will the wall be strong enough to hold the weight of the bike?

**EDIT**: Apparently I shouldn't be trying to damage my outdoor stucco, so it looks like I will be trying to find another way to hang the bike.

Comment: I strongly urge you not to damage your stucco wall by drilling into it to mount a bike rack. Stucco is a premium finish which should not be treated that way. I am a bike rider and I have a bike rack mounted to exterior cedar siding (10 inch "lap and gap") under a covered patio. This puts tremendous pull-out force on the screws. I suggest you make a freestanding stand for a rack or a stand which is based on one or two steel T-posts driven into the ground.

Comment: Like this https://www.google.com/shopping/product/6277162134303122658?lsf=seller:8740,store:9671194313301135564&prds=oid:3508789470515569331&q=t-post&hl=en&ei=Aro9WYCGHMfqjwO4sbWQDQ&lsft=cm_mmc%3DShopping-_-LIAs-_-D21-_-202023996&lsft=gclid:Cj0KCQjw1PPJBRDqARIsABNl38FEufpCdAdz2nDydJxfiaIrehI9o9FVGbKjw1UZMu6IMWHNZQy62BEaAlojEALw_wcB

Comment: @Jim Stewart unfortunately I can't drive anything into the ground because I am on an above ground level apartment

Comment: If this is a rental apartment, I can't believe your landlord would allow you to damage the exterior stucco by attaching a bike rack.  It would be unsightly and you would risk getting the bike stolen. Where is this apartment located--city and district?

Comment: The projecting pedals means that a rack mounted on a vertical wall must extend about 12" from the wall.  While living in rental digs in Oakland I brought my bike inside. In our house in Dallas TX I do hang it on an outside wall but in the fenced and locked backyard.

Comment: Post a photo of your exterior area. We can surely come up with better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I live north of Pittsburgh, Pa. and that stucco exterior finish was used on older commercial brick, stone or masonry buildings as a cheap insulation. It consisted of 2" white styrofoam board, covered with what we call "chicken wire" fencing, then that was covered with an exterior plaster type coating. I believe that the whole process was often called DRIVIT. You could not hang anything on it. I would follow Jim Stewart's advice as a solution

Comment: Also known as EIFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_insulation_finishing_system), but your point is correct: If it is that, and not real stucco, you definitely don't want to try and attach anything to (or more correctly _through_) it. Especially on a rental.